# Copying file from Unix to windows changes file name

Tags: java, windows, unix, character-encoding

I am creating some files with dynamic code and dynamic content via code deployed in a Unix system. The name of the file changes when it is placed in a windows shared path.

**E.G**

Suppose a file name was Ämber.xml which is created in unix system where my code is deployed. After the file creation is finished, it is placed in a windows shared path folder. In the windows shared path folder when I look at the file, the content is perfect but the name changes to Ãmber.xml.  So the Ä changes to Ã.
Could you please provide me a solution to this? Thank you.

Comment: Quick solution: Use only ASCII symbols for naming files.

Answer (score 0):

This is ultimately because an UTF-8 filename is interpreted as ISO (or another non-unicode) encoded string.

Probably the filename encoding is not configured correctly on the Unix system (or a buggy driver is used for mounting), so I'd try checking the mount options for the share. Details vary depending on the OS ("Unix" is pretty general).